# Matching cell to a range and inputing matched cells corresponding cell

Tags: openoffice-calc

I used "=IF(MATCH(A1;E$1:E$4;0);A1)" in Openoffice (FROM THIS AWESOME SITE) to search a range to match a cell. Is there a way to report the corresponding cell value of the matched range cell? E.g.

John, Cathy, Joe, Pat, Noob, Jack are in cells A1 through A6. A set of names in column C with dates or something else in column D. If for example, cell C3 = John, then I would like cell B1 (formula cell) to give me the value of cell D3. Similarly if cell C100 = Joe, then cell B3 should be filled with value of D100. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, someone downvoted without a comment.  The question seems okay to me as it provides a simplified, reproducible example.  However, it would be better to show a link for the source of the formula instead of "FROM THIS AWESOME SITE".

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in cell B1 and then fill down to B6.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1;C$1:D$100;2;0);"")
```

[image: results]

Documentation: [VLOOKUP](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VLOOKUP_function),
 [IFNA](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#IFNA).

Older versions such as AOO 4.1.3 do not have `IFNA`.  So for those versions, use `=VLOOKUP(A1;C$1:D$100;2;0)` or wrap it in a longer `IF` statement with `ISNA`.